# identifying strings within intervals, pt 2

Tags: awk

For each row, I would like to know if the numerical string in the 6th column resides within the start and end intervals of the 3rd and 4th column. The issue for me is that identical strings in the 1st and 5th column are not always in the same row (e.g., uce-6459 is on the same line as uce-432).

### Input

```
locus      match       start   end   subset   pos     region
uce-3280   uce-3280_p1 269     388   uce-3280 222     
uce-6620   uce-6620_p1 297     416   uce-6620 198     
uce-6620   uce-6620_p1 297     416   uce-6620 300     
uce-432    uce-432_p2  328     447   uce-432  205     
uce-432    uce-432_p1  268     387   uce-6459 207     
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-6459 275     
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-6459 288     
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-374  373     
uce-374    uce-374_p2  509     628   uce-3393 327     
uce-374    uce-374_p1  449     568   uce-3393 416     
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-3393 712     
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-1200 416     
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-805  397     
uce-1200   uce-1200_p3 341     460   uce-627  326     
uce-805    uce-805_p1  333     452   uce-2299 340     
uce-627    uce-627_p1  396     515   uce-2126 481     
uce-2299   uce-2299_p1 388     507   uce-5427 562     
uce-2126   uce-2126_p1 323     437   uce-5427 711     
uce-5427   uce-5427_p1 509     628   uce-5893 242     
uce-5427   uce-5427_p1 509     628   uce-5893 330     
uce-5893   uce-5893_p1 477     582   uce-5893 398
```

### Desired output

```
locus      match       start   end   subset   pos     region
uce-3280   uce-3280_p1 269     388   uce-3280 222     no
uce-6620   uce-6620_p1 297     416   uce-6620 198     no
uce-6620   uce-6620_p1 297     416   uce-6620 300     yes
uce-432    uce-432_p2  328     447   uce-432  205     no
uce-432    uce-432_p1  268     387   uce-6459 207     no
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-6459 275     yes
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-6459 288     yes
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-374  373     no
uce-374    uce-374_p2  509     628   uce-3393 327     no
uce-374    uce-374_p1  449     568   uce-3393 416     no
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-3393 712     no
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-1200 416     yes
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-805  397     yes
uce-1200   uce-1200_p3 341     460   uce-627  326     no
uce-805    uce-805_p1  333     452   uce-2299 340     no
uce-627    uce-627_p1  396     515   uce-2126 481     no
uce-2299   uce-2299_p1 388     507   uce-5427 562     yes
uce-2126   uce-2126_p1 323     437   uce-5427 711     no
uce-5427   uce-5427_p1 509     628   uce-5893 242     no
uce-5427   uce-5427_p1 509     628   uce-5893 330     no
uce-5893   uce-5893_p1 477     582   uce-5893 398     no
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase it: Second and third columns define functions `s: locus->start` and `e: locus->end`. For each line with index `k`, you want to check whether `pos(k)` is in the interval `[s(locus-subset(k)), e(locus-subset(k))]`.

Comment: I've found this pretty useful: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html
The most "complex" part are the RegExpressions, but you don't need them here at all.

Comment: @user3683803 throw that book away as it is hopelessly out of date. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robins instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full stand-alone `awk`-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# goes through the whole file, saves boundaries of the intervals
NR > 1 && NR == FNR {
  starts[$1] = $3
  ends[$1] = $4
  #print "Scanned interval: "$1" = ["starts[$1]","ends[$1]"]"
}

# prints the header of the table
NR != FNR && FNR == 1 {
  print $0
}

# annotates each line with "yes"/"no"
FNR > 1 && NR != FNR {
  print $0"    "(starts[$5] <= $6 && $6 <= ends[$5] ? "yes" : "no")
}
```

Depending on what OS you have and what `awk` you are using, you might need to adjust the first line (use `which awk` to find the right path).
 In order to make it run, you have to save it in a separate file (e.g. `analyzeSnp.awk`), then make it executable (e.g. `chmod u+x analyzeSnp.awk`), and then run it like this:

```
./analyzeSnp.awk inputData inputData
```

Alternatively, you can enclose it in single quotes and paste it directly into the console like this:

```
$ awk '    #!/usr/bin/awk -f

# goes through the whole file, saves boundaries of the intervals
NR > 1 && NR == FNR {
  starts[$1] = $3
  ends[$1] = $4
  #print "Scanned interval: "$1" = ["starts[$1]","ends[$1]"]"
}

# prints the header of the table
NR != FNR && FNR == 1 {
  print $0
}

# annotates each line with "yes"/"no"
FNR > 1 && NR != FNR {
  print $0"    "(starts[$5] <= $6 && $6 <= ends[$5] ? "yes" : "no")
}' loci.txt loci.txt
```

Important: you have to specify your input file *twice*, because we need a first scan to build a table with intervals, and then a second scan for actual annotation.

Here is the produced output:

```
locus      match       start   end   subset   pos     region
uce-3280   uce-3280_p1 269     388   uce-3280 222     no
uce-6620   uce-6620_p1 297     416   uce-6620 198     no
uce-6620   uce-6620_p1 297     416   uce-6620 300     yes
uce-432    uce-432_p2  328     447   uce-432  205     no
uce-432    uce-432_p1  268     387   uce-6459 207     no
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-6459 275     yes
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-6459 288     yes
uce-6459   uce-6459_p1 210     329   uce-374  373     no
uce-374    uce-374_p2  509     628   uce-3393 327     no
uce-374    uce-374_p1  449     568   uce-3393 416     no
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-3393 712     no
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-1200 416     yes
uce-3393   uce-3393_p1 439     558   uce-805  397     yes
uce-1200   uce-1200_p3 341     460   uce-627  326     no
uce-805    uce-805_p1  333     452   uce-2299 340     no
uce-627    uce-627_p1  396     515   uce-2126 481     no
uce-2299   uce-2299_p1 388     507   uce-5427 562     yes
uce-2126   uce-2126_p1 323     437   uce-5427 711     no
uce-5427   uce-5427_p1 509     628   uce-5893 242     no
uce-5427   uce-5427_p1 509     628   uce-5893 330     no
uce-5893   uce-5893_p1 477     582   uce-5893 398     no
```

This looks pretty close to your example snippet.

A general remark: AWK is a surprisingly *modern* and powerful scripting language (at least for it's age: this thing is almost 40 years old!). If you want to use AWK, you are not constrained to cryptic single-liners.